# I don't understand why firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) does not work

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web-applications

I am trying to make a login page using firebase, I am very new to this and have been reading through the firebase documentation to find a solution to my problem.

This is my function using the firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword() method from the firebase auth SDK.

```js
function toggleSignIn() {

    var email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('inputPass').value;

    if (email.length < 1) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
    }
    if (password.length < 1) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
    }
    // Sign in with email and pass.
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

This will run once in a blue moon, but will stop running after that.
I click my 'Login_buton' on my HTML page, and it just clears the input email, and input password boxes.
Nothing happens after that, I check my console window and there is no user signed in.

This is what the HTML looks like

```html
 <div id="Login-google" class="input-group-google">
                <button id="Logout_buton" type="submit" class="submit-buton" onclick="toggleSignOut()"> Test Logout </button>
            </div>

            <form id="Login" class="input-group">
                <input id="inputEmail" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input id="inputPass" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"> <span> Remember Password </span>
                <button id="Login_buton" type="submit" class="submit-buton" onclick="toggleSignIn()"> Test Login </button>
            </form>
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, I am very new to this please be easy on me.

Comment: try this way:
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success 
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
       // Error Handling
  });

Comment: unfortunately it didn't run, is there some kind of lag in firebase.auth().SignIn where after logging out, you might not be able login again for a while. Also, I have firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged but I don't think it is responsible for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting a form, the default browser behaviour submits the form by making a POST request to the given URL. If you want to prevent the default behaviour you need to write `e.preventDefault()` in your submit method. Here is the updated code.

Use forms onsubmit event to submit the form

Javascript

```js
function toggleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behaviour

    var email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('inputPass').value;

    if (email.length < 1) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
    }
    if (password.length < 1) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
    }
    // Sign in with email and pass.
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
  // do something when sign in is successful
}).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

HTML

```html
 <div id="Login-google" class="input-group-google">
                <button id="Logout_buton" type="submit" class="submit-buton" onclick="toggleSignOut()"> Test Logout </button>
            </div>

            <form id="Login" class="input-group" onsubmit="return toggleSignIn(event)">
                <input id="inputEmail" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input id="inputPass" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"> <span> Remember Password </span>
                <button id="Login_button" type="submit" class="submit-button"> Test Login </button>
            </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize what forms did in HTML I should have looked into it sooner. I was able to get it running after adding your code. I am extremely grateful for your help :).

Comment: Great, If you found this helpful, please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: it says that I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: you can accept, by clicking on that tick icon